# convert json string into php object and access it's value

Tags: php, json

I have json data as shown in the picture below, how do I get highlighted value and change them?

[Json Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajIel.png)

**EDITED**

I try to get the "furniture_id" using the code below...but fails...I don't know what else i can do to get the value

```
$test = '{"data":[{"owned_id":1,"furniture_id":1,"owned_name":"desk_123"},{"owned_id":2,"furniture_id":2,"owned_name":"chair_123"},{"owned_id":3,"furniture_id":4,"owned_name":"sofa_123"}]}';

    foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
        dd($furniture_id['id']);
    }
```

Comment: mm.. your code / efforts?

Comment: ive updated my question, see edited

Comment: `$test = json_decode($test);`

Comment: You need to convert a json-string into the actual array by `json_decode()`. After that you will be able to change values, and, if you wish, convert it back to the string by `json_encode()`.

Comment: what you can use is json_decode to convert json string to php object.I've explained in my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test = '{"data":[{"owned_id":1,"furniture_id":1,"owned_name":"desk_123"},{"owned_id":2,"furniture_id":2,"owned_name":"chair_123"},{"owned_id":3,"furniture_id":4,"owned_name":"sofa_123"}]}';
    $response=json_decode($test);

        foreach ($response->data as $key => $value) {
           echo $value->furniture_id;
echo "<br>";
        }
```

first you have to decode json data using json_encode method.Then if you print json decode response then you will be get an result of standard object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [owned_id] => 1
                    [furniture_id] => 1
                    [owned_name] => desk_123
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [owned_id] => 2
                    [furniture_id] => 2
                    [owned_name] => chair_123
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [owned_id] => 3
                    [furniture_id] => 4
                    [owned_name] => sofa_123
                )

        )

)
```

Updated

```
$test = '{"data":[{"owned_id":1,"furniture_id":1,"owned_name":"desk_123"},{"owned_id":2,"furniture_id":2,"owned_name":"chair_123"},{"owned_id":3,"furniture_id":4,"owned_name":"sofa_123"}]}';
$response=json_decode($test);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
$newArray=[];
    foreach ($response->data as $key => $value) {
    $row=[];
       $value->furniture_id= $value->furniture_id+1;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response->data);
```

Now output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [owned_id] => 1
            [furniture_id] => 2
            [owned_name] => desk_123
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [owned_id] => 2
            [furniture_id] => 3
            [owned_name] => chair_123
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [owned_id] => 3
            [furniture_id] => 5
            [owned_name] => sofa_123
        )

)
```

Comment: i used your code, it works fine. But the problem is, how do i change the value of each $value->furniture_id and save it in the same $test

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$test = '{"data":[{"owned_id":1,"furniture_id":1,"owned_name":"desk_123"},{"owned_id":2,"furniture_id":2,"owned_name":"chair_123"},{"owned_id":3,"furniture_id":4,"owned_name":"sofa_123"}]}';

$test = json_decode($test, true);

//if you want to change value of furniture_id in index 0 
$test['data'][0]['furniture_id'] = 111;
print_r($test); exit;
```

Comment: i used your code, it works fine. But the problem is, how do i change the value of each $value->furniture_id and save it in the same $test

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = '{"data":[{"owned_id":1,"furniture_id":1,"owned_name":"desk_123"},{"owned_id":2,"furniture_id":2,"owned_name":"chair_123"},{"owned_id":3,"furniture_id":4,"owned_name":"sofa_123"}]}';
```

this `$test` string itself is a `json string`.As json is similar to javascript object, there is no way to to store json as we can do in javascript.That's why we put json inside a quote in php and represent them as string.

what you can do is turn the json string into a php object using `json_decode()` and access them in foreach loop

```
foreach (json_decode($test)->data as $key) {

    echo $key->furniture_id;
}
```